# How do I Find WeekOff using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm writing basic JavaScript function to get If today is working day or not from a list of Working Sequences.

JavaScript

```
function IsWeekOff(ToDay, WorkingSequence) {
        var Sun_Thu = {0:"Sun",1:"Mon",2:"Tue",3:"Wed",4:"Thu"};
        var Thu_Mon = {4:"Thu",5:"Fri",6:"Sat",0:"Sun",1:"Mon"};
        var Tue_Sat = {2:"Tue",3:"Wed",4:"Thu",5:"Fri",6:"Sat"};

        if (WorkingSequence == "Sun-Thu") {
            for (ToDay in Sun_Thu){
                return "P";
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (WorkingSequence == "Thu-Mon") {
            for (ToDay in Thu_Mon){
                return "P";
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (WorkingSequence == "Tue-Sat") {
            for (ToDay in Tue_Sat){
                return "P";
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            return "O";
        }

    }
```

I'm getting all "P" s for every criteria

When we Passing today, and Working Sequence to the function, it should return "P" or "O" based on criteria.

Comment: What does this function is supposed to do? what means "P" and "O" ? And what is the possible values of parameters `ToDay` and `WorkingSequence` ?

Comment: Using `for in` is most likely the wrong  tool for this

Comment: The `for` clause will iterate over the `Sun_Thu`/`Thu_Mon`/`Tue_Sat` sequences and for each item will `return 'P'`, at the same time the first return 'P' executed will end up the function execution. The only way for that function to return `'O'` is to pass an invalid `WorkingSequence` to the function.

Additionally any code below a `return` statement won't be executed. So the `break`s on each block, make no sense.

Comment: `for (ToDay in Sun_Thu){` I do not think that is doing what you think it is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar approach to the other answer, but using the current day of the week to get the result.

```js
function isTodayWorkingDay(seq) {

  const sequences = {
      st: [0,1,2,3,4],
      tm: [4,5,6,7,8],
      ts: [2,3,4,5,6]
    },
    today = new Date().getDay();
    
  if (sequences[seq].includes(today)) {
    return 'Got to work today!';
  } else {
    return 'Nice one, day off!';
  }
  
}

console.log ('If we are working Sat to Thu, ' + isTodayWorkingDay('st'));
console.log ('If we are working Thu to Mon, ' + isTodayWorkingDay('tm'));
console.log ('If we are working Tue to Sat, ' + isTodayWorkingDay('ts'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to create an object keyed by the `WorkingSequence` string. You can then place arrays containing the the `dayOfWeek` values in to these arrays. Finally in the function you can retrieve the array and use `indexOf()` to determine if it holds the dayOfWeek and return `O` or `P` as required. Try this:

```js
var sequences = {
  Sun_Thu: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
  Thur_Mon: [4, 5, 6, 0, 1],
  Tue_Sat: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

function isWeekOff(dayOfWeek, workingSequence) {
  return sequences[workingSequence].indexOf(dayOfWeek) === -1 ? 'O' : 'P';
}

console.log(isWeekOff(1, 'Sun_Thu')); // P
console.log(isWeekOff(1, 'Thur_Mon')); // P
console.log(isWeekOff(1, 'Tue_Sat')); // O
```

Comment: In addition to this code you could create constants instead of plan "magic numbers". This shouldn't change the logic of this code, but will increase readability. For example, declare: `const Days = { SUN: 0, MON: 1, TUE: 2, WED: 3, THU: 4, FRI: 5, SAT: 6 }`, then every time you need to pass the day to the function you can use it like: `isWeekOff(Days.TUE, 'Sun_Thu')`. You could do the same for the sequences.